# How to find the whole hierarchy of parent folders for a Google Drive file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I can use the Google Drive API to do this:

```
drive.files.get(
  {
    fields: "parents",
    fileId: "######"
  },
  (err, results) => {
    ...
  }
);
```

However, I can only get the ID of the folder, one level up from the file.

How can I get the whole hierarchy of parent folders that contain the Google Drive file, the folder that contains the folder, the folder that contains that folder, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this method? I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as one of them. Unfortunately, all folders including subfolders in a folder cannot be retrieved using `files.get` of Drive API. And when `q` is used for `files.list` of Drive API, `'folder ID' in parents` retrieves only folders in folder ID. Folders under the subfolder in folder ID cannot be retrieved. So in this method, I used the following flow.

1. Retrieve all folders in Google Drive.

   - In this sample script, if the number of folders in your Google Drive is less than 1000, all folders are retrieved by one API call. If the number of folders is from 1000 to 2000, 2 API calls are used.
2. Create the folder tree using the list of all folders.

#### Sample script :

```
function run(auth) {
    var drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: auth});
    getFolderTree(drive, "", []);
}

function getFolderTree(drive, nextPageToken, folderList) {
    drive.files.list({
        pageToken: nextPageToken ? nextPageToken : "",
        pageSize: 1000,
        q: "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
        fields: "files(id,parents),nextPageToken",
    }, (err, {data}) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        const token = data.nextPageToken;
        Array.prototype.push.apply(folderList, data.files);
        if (token) {
            getFolderTree(drive, token, folderList);
        } else {

            // This script retrieves all folders including subfolders under this folder ID.
            const folderId = "### Top folder ID ###";

            const folderTree = function c(folder, folderSt, res) {
                let ar = folderList.filter(e => e.parents[0] == folder);
                folderSt += folder + "#_aabbccddee_#";
                let arrayFolderSt = folderSt.split("#_aabbccddee_#");
                arrayFolderSt.pop();
                res.push(arrayFolderSt);
                ar.length == 0 && (folderSt = "");
                ar.forEach(e => c(e.id, folderSt, res));
                return res;
            }(folderId, "", []);

            // Output the folder tree.
            console.log(folderTree);
        }
    });
}
```

#### Output :

When the folder structure is as follows. (You can set the top folder ID in this sample script.)

[image]

This script creates an array as follows.

```
[
  ['topFolderId'],
  ['topFolderId','folderId_2a'],
  ['topFolderId','folderId_2b'],
  ['topFolderId','folderId_2b','folderId_3a'],
  ['topFolderId','folderId_2b','folderId_3b']
]
```

#### Note :

- I confirmed that this sample script worked at the googleapis with v30.0.0.
- In generally, the folder tree is created by retrieving folders from the top folder in order. But when Drive API is used for this situation, if there are a lot of folders in the top folder, a lot of APIs are required to be called. So in this method, I have tried to create the folder tree with a small number of API calls using a list of all folders.
- This is a simple sample script, so please modify this to your environment.

#### References :

- [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters)

### Edit :

This updated script retrieves the whole folder tree including the inputted folderId. For above script, `run()` and `getFolderTree()` were modified.

```
function run(auth) {
    var drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: auth});
    drive.files.get({fileId: "root", fields: "id"}, (err, {data}) => {
      getFolderTree(drive, "", [], data.id);
    });
}

function getFolderTree(drive, nextPageToken, folderList, rootId) {
    drive.files.list({
        pageToken: nextPageToken ? nextPageToken : "",
        pageSize: 1000,
        q: "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
        fields: "files(id,name,parents),nextPageToken",
    }, (err, {data}) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        const token = data.nextPageToken;
        Array.prototype.push.apply(folderList, data.files);
        if (token) {
            getFolderTree(drive, token, folderList, rootId);
        } else {

            // Please input folder ID.
            const inputId = "### Folder ID ###";

            const folderId = rootId;
            const folderTree = function c(folder, folderSt, res) {
                let ar = folderList.filter(e => e.parents[0] == folder);
                folderSt += folder + "#_aabbccddee_#";
                let arrayFolderSt = folderSt.split("#_aabbccddee_#");
                arrayFolderSt.pop();
                res.push(arrayFolderSt);
                ar.length == 0 && (folderSt = "");
                ar.forEach(e => c(e.id, folderSt, res));
                return res;
            }(folderId, "", []);
            let result = folderTree.filter(e => ~e.indexOf(inputId));
            if (result.length > 2) result.shift();

            // Output result.
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

For the above, when `folderId_2b` is inputted to `inputId`, the following result can be retrieved.

```
[
    ["topFolderId","folderId_2b","folderId_3a"],
    ["topFolderId","folderId_2b","folderId_3b"]
]
```

Comment: I can see how this solution works; however, I was thinking more of a solution that didn't involve recursive API requests. Nonetheless, I thank you for your time and effort on this answer.

Comment: @think123 Thank you for your response. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I understand that you want to retrieve the folder list by fewer number of API calls. If my understanding is correct, my sample uses the recursive API request for only retrieving folders. In this case, if the number of folders under the folder you give is less than 1000, only one API call is used. Then, after the all folders under the folder you give are retrieved, the folder tree is created without API calls. Is my understanding for your comment correct?

Comment: In such a case, how could I make this work the other way round, i.e. given a folder ID, find all of its parents, as opposed to looking down the tree?

Comment: @think123 I'm really sorry. Now I thought that I may misunderstand your question. For example, when it uses the image of my answer, when you set "folderId_2b", you want to retrieve "topFolderId", "folderId_2b", "folderId_3a" and "folderId_3b". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Ideally, I want a script that takes in "folderId_3b", and from it I can get "folderId_2b" and "topFolderId", i.e. its parent, and the parent of its parent.

Comment: @think123 Thank you for replying. I think that I could understand what you want to do. So I updated my answer. Please confirm it.